# Running a JavaScript file via Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, window.open

Starting a project and off to a bad start. For now, I just want to run a .js file and have it open a browser window. I am using an HTML file to execute the .js via Safari. I checked the console in Safari and it seems to be finding/running the file just fine with no errors. See code below. Any help would be appreciated.

JavaScript

```
function doWork() {

myWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com","mywindow");

}
```

HTML

```
<HTML>
<Body>
    Local Site for running weatherGetter script.
<script src="work.js"> </script>
</Body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function in your javascript file is not used.

```
<HTML>
<Body onload="doWork()">
    Local Site for running weatherGetter script.
<script src="work.js"> </script>
</Body>
</HTML>
```

To solve it

Answer (score 1):

You've defined your function doWork() but you haven't actually called it.

Your JS should be something like:

```
function doWork() {

   myWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com","mywindow");

}

doWork();
```

Also, your html structure is incorrect.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/zupoyolo/1/ - There is a JSBIN. It works fine for me and I'm using safari :)

Comment: If so, that's a pretty shocking indictment of Safari's popup blocker; blocking popups on load is really, really basic. Any decent browser will prevent the popup. Certainly doesn't work in Chrome, Firefox, IE9, IE10, IE11, heck even IE8 manages to block it. The only Safari I have handy is iOS Safari on my iPhone (iOS 7), and it doesn't work there, either.

Answer (score 0):

1. `<head>` is missing, so invalid HTML
2. You aren't calling the function anywhere. So that's redundant.
3. Path might be wrong
4. You have not yet learned the basics. Please do that to save yourself a lot of head ache.

Answer (score 0):

With any modern browser, you can't open a window except in direct response to a *user action*.

As mickzer pointed out, you're defining your function but not calling it. But even if you added a call to it, the browser would prevent the window from opening (in any decent browser).

To successfully open the window, hook a user event and call your `doWork` function there, such as in response to a `click` hander.